# Kotlin initialization: how to fail

Tags: kotlin, initialization

I need to parse Firebase `DataSnapshot` (a JSON object) into a data class, whose properties include enum and list. So I prefer parsing it manually by passing the `DataSnapshot` into a secondary constructor. However, I want the construction to fail if some fields are missing in the `DataSnapshot`. In Swift, it has failable initializer that returns null so I know it has failed. How to do that in Kotlin?

The following is my attempt, but I assume you can't just return from a constructor, right?

```
data class Unit(val name: String, val type: UnitType, val components: List<Component>) {
    constructor(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        name = snapshot.child("name").value as? String ?: return
        val typeString = snapshot.child("type").value as? String ?: return
        type = UnitType.values().firstOrNull { it.abbrv == typeString } ?: return
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: While You can't return, You can throw an Exception which will allow caller to properly handle failed construction. Also I would not call a class in Kotlin as `Unit` since it's a built-in type for void and that could lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't just return from a constructor - it doesn't make much sense conceptually - but since I'm fairly naive on Kotlin syntax, I'll answer to a more broad paradigm here.

Your data class is not responsible for error checking or error handling.  It is only responsible for storing data.  Therefore, you should rely on a factory pattern to parse the result of a `DataSnapshot` and conditionally instantiate a new instance of `Unit` if and only if no fields are missing.

Comment: I would argue that factory is intended for initialization that requires dependency injection and state management. For simple task of creating a data class, it seems overkill (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). But still, thanks for a solution

Comment: @JGuo:  You have to bear in mind that Kotlin isn't Swift.  Swift could easily be abstracting away the whole factory pattern and providing what you describe as syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 6):

There is the `require` function which was designed for this purpose:

```
// ...
init {
    require(foo == "bar") {
        "$foo should be equal to 'bar'"
    }
}
```

There is also `requireNotNull`, `check`, `error` and some others. These are called *Preconditions* in Kotlin. There is no magic here, they are just some helper functions. You can check the actual source [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Preconditions.kt), it is very useful. There is a related blog post about the topic [here](https://medium.com/codeexplorers/a-quick-look-into-kotlin-preconditions-9a2d53c8c8ca).

Comment: We can also throw Exceptions. Kotlin doc [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html)